# Wordpress arrows dissapeared strange signs

Tags: plugins, templates

Good morning!

I don't know when but suddenly arrows in plugin "Slider Revolution" dissapeared. It could be only Slider Revolution error but I have noticed that arrow which is used to scroll page to the top also dissapeared and in both there are strange unicode sign "f106", "E825" ?

Does anybody have any kind of solution to this problem? I have Wordpress version 4.9.6.

Here are screenshots and the last from preview:
[image]

[image]

and how it should be:

[image]

Comment: check into inspect elements to console it's give any error or not? I think  it's give fontaswome error or any css error.

Comment: There is an error: https://fachowiec.com/pkftp/blad.jpg        Also here is the link to the page: http://welderfantasy.com/

Comment: Is this happening because my site doesn't have SSL certificate ?

Comment: No. You're trying to load a font from http://pneumatic.home.pl, but your site/server's security policy is not allowing resources from that domain. Is that website also yours? Why are you trying to load fonts from another website?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess code.

REF 1: https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

REF 2:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```